# how to switch to another page in 3 seconds in PHP?

Tags: php, refresh

Here is my try:

```
@header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
@header("Location:/index.php");
@header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
@header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

As you have seen,there is no control over "3 seconds",how to make it take effect in 3 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work, in PHP:

```
header('Refresh: 3; url=index.php');
```

Comment: how is this supported by different browsers?

Comment: AFAIK, it's supported by all major browsers.

Comment: Just note that this code has to come before any other php code on the page.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is to use a [`meta` redirect](http://webmaster.indiana.edu/tool_guide_info/refresh_metatag.shtml) or a javascript redirect.  Saying as how you are serving text/html, you can echo either of these to the browser.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=/newpage.php">
```

or

```
window.setTimeout(function() { window.location = '/newpage.php' }, 3000);
```

Edit: According to the Wikipedia page on [URL redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) you can send the `Refresh` header directly to the browser from PHP.  No clue on how well browsers support this though.

```
header('Refresh: 3; url=/newpage.php');
```

Comment: I remember seeing a PHP function that would output both. Don't really need to go hunt it down - the Asker could implement that.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the refresh meta tag, like this:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>redirect page</title> 
    <META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.newurl.com"> 
</head> 
<body bgcolor="#ffffff"> 
    The contents you are looking for have moved. 
    You will be redirected to the new location automatically in 5 seconds.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        @if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success container">
        {{ Session::get('success') }}
        @php
        header("refresh:3;url=/load_applications_one");
            Session::forget('success');
        @endphp
    </div>
```

@endif

Comment: Please edit your answer explaining your code, use 4 spaces to indent the code :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).